# What measures should be taken to avoid outgoing emails being delivered to spam

Tags: php, email-spam

We have set the TXT/SPF record as advised by hostgator team but still all emails are being delivered to spam. Unable to get proper information from them to fix this.

Could someone please advice what all measures to be taken to avoid outgoing emails being delivered to spam.

This is only recently that emails are being delivered at spam earlier it was working fine. We are using php mail() function.

Many Thanks
Hema

Answer (score 0):

See this question and answers on our sister site Pro Webmasters: [How could I prevent my mail from being recognized as spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/3728/1253). It answers your question in detail.

Comment: After getting in touch with hostgator they advised that PTR & SPF is already set. Do I need to get in touch regarding domain keys set up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your e-mail is of a good length, doesn't have too many non dictionary words, doesn't mention viagra, cialis or Canadian Pharmacies.

Ensure the  address points at a domain that exists and that you control.

We tend to include a foreword about the company in question or the service you are providing. Try not to include too many URLs, and if you do, try to ensure that the words within those URLs are dictionary words.

Also look at the SpamAssassin scoring table to see if any of the components of your e-mail will score highly: http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_3_x.html